# How to use parent class by configuration in child class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have class `ParentImageTransformation` with the method `getResolution`. Now I have a new class `ChildImageTransformation` with the overwritten method `getResolution`. I have a configuration which tells me, if I need to use the overwritten method.

Is it possible to instantiate the `ChildImageTransformation` class, so that it uses the correct `getResolution` method by the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to define it as such:

```
class ChildImageTransformation extends ParentImageTransformation {
  private boolean useParent;

  public ChildImageTransformation(boolean useParent) {
    this.useParent = useParent;
  }

  public int getResolution() {
    if (useParent) {
      return super.getResolution();
    } else {
      return <something>;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate the class and the method will delegate to the superclass if you set the boolean to `true`.

Comment: Hi, my question is about how to avoid the `useParent` check in the `getResolution` method. Is it possible to instantiate the class, so that I can use it for all possible methods "out of box".

Comment: You could pass a lambda into the constructor that defines the getResolution method implementation?